# Is it possible to set up a custom domain with GitHub Pages, but keep the original github.io link working without redirection?

Tags: github, github-pages

Is there any way I can set up a custom domain with GitHub Pages (e.g. `www.vinyanalista.com.br`), but also keep the original `github.io` link working (e.g. `vinyanalista.github.io`)? That way, my website could be accessed by both addresses (`www.vinyanalista.com.br` or `vinyanalista.github.io`) without redirection.

Now, what is happening is:

- http://vinyanalista.github.io (my GitHub user page) is automatically redirected to http://www.vinyanalista.com.br (my custom domain)
- http://vinyanalista.github.io/blog/2015/06/24/favicon/ (a post of my blog) is automatically redirected to http://www.vinyanalista.com.br/blog/2015/06/24/favicon/
- http://vinyanalista.github.io/portugol (a website for a project of mine) is automatically redirected to http://www.vinyanalista.com.br/portugol

The setting I want is:

- http://vinyanalista.github.io can be accessed without redirection (i.e. the URL in the address bar does not change)
- http://www.vinyanalista.com.br can be accessed without redirection
- http://vinyanalista.github.io/blog/2015/06/24/favicon/ can be accessed without redirection
- http://www.vinyanalista.com.br/blog/2015/06/24/favicon/ can be accessed without redirection
- http://vinyanalista.github.io/portugol can be accessed without redirection
- http://www.vinyanalista.com.br/portugol can be accessed without redirection (although I don't really mind this use case, because I want http://vinyanalista.github.io/portugol to be accessed that way, as it was before I set up `www.vinyanalista.com.br` as a custom domain for `vinyanalista.github.io`)

Thanks in advice!

**Edit:** my DNS setup right now is:

```
Host    -        IP/Address
@       A        192.30.252.153
@       MX 5     ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@       MX 10    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@       MX 15    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@       MX 20    ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@       MX 25    ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@       A        192.30.252.154
mail    CNAME    ghs.google.com.
www     CNAME    vinyanalista.github.io.
```

Comment: What resource records do you currently have set up for your domain?

Comment: @RedRoboHood, thank you for the help! I edited my question, please see my domain's resource records there.

Comment: The one who downvoted my question can please explain me why I deserve a downvote? That way I can improve, this is my first question on SO!

Comment: I don't have much experience in this area; I've set up a GitHub Pages site on a custom domain much like you have, with email forwarding to and from a Gmail address, but that's it. My best guess is that you should remove the CNAME file from your repository and find some way to have your custom domain look for files in the parallel structure of your GitHub Pages domain. The problem is that any link you code into your website will need to point to either a page in your GitHub Pages domain or a page in your custom domain, and not both. Good luck!